# Is there a way to group nodes in a Networkx graph together based on how connected they are?

Tags: python, networking, graph, networkx

I have 39 people who have listed preferences for who they would like to be in a group with. I have input this data into a NetworkX graph in Python. I want to use the NetworkX graph to create groups of three based off how people are connected to eachother.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide code samples so other developers can advise you on how to solve your issue with NetworkX

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to identify communities. Here is a possible solution (`G` is your graph, built using the `networkx` module):

```
from networkx.algorithms.community import greedy_modularity_communities

c = list(greedy_modularity_communities(G))
```

You can get very different outputs (i.e., people can be divided in communities in different ways). This depends on the algorithm that you choose.